# Why is my MySQL result incorrect when I use GROUP BY?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple table (ID, Member_ID, payment, date, payment_serial, running_total); I need the payment_serial to use the data for export to another system.

The export I need is all the payments made by a member (showing payment & date), sorted in order of the payment_serial and in a single row.

This was the first query I used:

```
SELECT
  `Member_ID`,
  IF(`payment_serial`=1,`payment`,0) AS `p1`,
  IF(`payment_serial`=1,`date`,0) AS `p1_date`,
  IF(`payment_serial`=1,`ID`,0) AS `p1_ID`,
  IF(`payment_serial`=2,`payment`,0) AS `p2`,
  IF(`payment_serial`=2,`date`,0) AS `p2_date`
  IF(`payment_serial`=2,`ID`,0) AS `p2_ID`,
FROM monthlies
WHERE `Member_ID` = 4198739
```

If I use this query, I see the payments I need, but each on a separate row (which creates big import problems at the next stage):

```
Member_ID    p1     p1_date  p1_ID    p2    p2_date  p2_ID ...
  4198739   34.50    41143    214      0      0       0    ... 
  4198739     0        0       0     34.50  41176    583   ...
```

I added GROUP BY:

```
SELECT
  IF(`payment_serial`=1,`payment`,0) AS `p1`,
  IF(`payment_serial`=1,`date`,0) AS `p1_date`,
  IF(`payment_serial`=1,`ID`,0) AS `p1_ID`,
  IF(`payment_serial`=2,`payment`,0) AS `p2`,
  IF(`payment_serial`=2,`date`,0) AS `p2_date`,
  IF(`payment_serial`=2,`ID`,0) AS `p2_ID`
FROM monthlies
WHERE `Member_ID` = 4198739
GROUP BY `Member_ID`
```

This gives me a single row for each member - but **not** each payment:

```
Member_ID    p1     p1_date  p1_ID    p2    p2_date  p2_ID ...
  4198739   34.50    41143    214      0      0       0    ...
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely your fault. MySQL implements GROUP BY wrong. Any other SQL platform would give you a syntax error at this point.

Try

```
SELECT 
  MAX(IF(`payment_serial`=1,`payment`,0)) AS `p1`, 
  MAX(IF(`payment_serial`=1,`date`,0)) AS `p1_date`, 
  MAX(IF(`payment_serial`=1,`ID`,0)) AS `p1_ID`, 
  MAX(IF(`payment_serial`=2,`payment`,0)) AS `p2`, 
  MAX(IF(`payment_serial`=2,`date`,0)) AS `p2_date`, 
  MAX(IF(`payment_serial`=2,`ID`,0)) AS `p2_ID` 
FROM monthlies 
WHERE `Member_ID` = 4198739 
GROUP BY `Member_ID`
```

Comment: Why do you say that MYSQL implements wrong the GROUP BY? Reference? Please don't compare SQL platform.

Comment: Good link, but again, against what? T-SQL? What is the reference? I think that MySQL just another point of view of so many things, some good, some bad, it depends on how do you work. I don't think is an objective error. Anyway thanks for the reference, +1 point

Comment: I don't know any other implementation that allows this interpretation of group by. You can read http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt if you like :)

Comment: Thanks @podiluska: exactly what I need, and I understand GROUP BY better than I did (which isn't difficult, admittedly).

Answer (score 1):

You are expecting the wrong output from GROUP_BY. In MySQL `GROUP_BY` is used in conjunction with commands like `MAX, AVG, SUM` etc to get all the results in a consolidated row.

So if you want to export the data the best way is to get all the rows without using group by as it will retain each row with its unique member id.

Comment: Thanks @shubhanshu - the link between GROUP BY and MAX etc. had passed me by.

Answer (score 0):

The GROUP BY is previous to the IF of the SELECT.